# Capture RWin +L or LWin+L with C#

Tags: c#, keyboard-events, keyboard-hook

So I'm trying to make an application in C# that executes some code **before** one locks his/her computer with Windows Key+L.

I don't have any experience with keyboard hooks whatsoever. I searched the web and found a nice implementation of a keyboard hook: [Low-Level Keyboard Hook in C#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c/)

However, since the LWin and RWin key aren't modifier keys (as far as I understand), I cannot get the above mentioned example working for my case.

Does anyone have some sources and/or examples on how I can capture the LWin+L or RWin+L key combination?

I failed to find examples or information about how to prevent windows from locking itself with the Win+L key combination too. Is this even possible? If yes, how would I be able to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are also able to the lock the computer from the ctrl+alt+del screen. Do you need to capture this event as well?

Comment: @Sunshine Not necessarily, but if i can somehow capture a "windows lock" event or something, that would be sufficient.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/734037/7055056 Has an example of a windows service that listens for session event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/

This sends Win32 SendInput methods to C#. This allows you to directly send the windows key. This will work:

InputSimulator.SimulateModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.LWIN, VirtualKeyCode.VK_L);